# HTML email hack for width

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am hoping someone can help me out here.

MANY months ago, I came on here looking for an answer to why my email wasn't displaying at 600px on a certain email client(I can't remember which one but it's probably Gmail). I have been using the following code over the last  few months:

```
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
style="margin: auto;" width="600px;" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:600px;" >
```

For the life of me, I cannot remember **why** the width is defined in both px and without px on the table. Then defined again on the TD in 600px. I've Googled it like crazy but no answers so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is unclear about what the issue is and what you attempted to solve it. Please provide a better definition of the issue and consider adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Three lines of opening tags don't give much context.

Answer (score 0):

### Setting the `width` of a table

- In a nut-shell, there are two ways to set a `width` for `table` or its inner elements (e.g. `tr`, `td`, etc—which support `width`)

  1. **Using `width` property**: as part of HTML spec, you can use `width` property as part of the markup. Like you have `width="600"` in your `table` tag. Please note, however, **only numeric pixel value or percentage is valid**  (https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-width-TABLE )
  2. **Using inline `style` property or CSS declaration**: Like how you have `style: 600px;` in your `td`. Here, any valid CSS units can be used.
- While it's typically considered a bad practice to use HTML markup for styling or/and rely heavily on inline styling, for HTML emails not only rely on both—often used simultaneously. Because, well, HTML emails are its own kind of beast.

### Why `table` width doesn't render as intended

It's hard to answer with specific context. Table cells could collapse when there's no content inside, which might affect the widths of their containing elements. There might have been a typo. There might have been an invalid value used in a style declaration. There might have been a conflicting style definition. Or any number of other factors.

Answer (score 0):

The only needed way to set a `width` on a `<table>` **for an HTML email** is to use an inline style.

```html
<table style="width:600px; margin:auto; background-color:#fff;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
```

This is the best way to do it because it will take into account *The Outlooks* on Windows at 120dpi rendering. This is also a personal recommandation of mine to prefer [styles over attributes](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-guidelines#styles-over-attributes), which is why I moved the `background-color` in a `style` as well above.

The only exception to this is for images. *The Outlooks* on Windows don’t understand a `width` style on images, only a `width` attribute. So you always need to define a fixed width for Outlook on Windows in an HTML attribute, and then a fluid width in a style for other clients if you need it.

```html
<!-- Bad example -->
<img src="example.jpg" alt="" width="100%" />

<!-- Good example -->
<img src="example.jpg" alt="" width="600" style="width:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use **1 - 100 %** at the place of **px**